# Eclipse not showing all variables in viewer during debug mode

Tags: eclipse-cdt

Short question, why is it that the variables that are declared in my header file don't show up in the Variables window during debug mode? Only when I move the declaration from the header file to the source file do I have the option of viewing them within this viewer.

Can someone tell me if there's also a way to view the other variables?

Comment: I have tried to provide an answer, but there are some open questions. If I haven't answered your question, can you provide a code example of what does not work as you expect and I or others can tell you how we use the tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Expressions` view to view non-local variables. Open the view (*Window* menu -> *Show View* -> *Expressions*) and add the variables of interest. There are some context menu items if you select a variable or expression (with associated short-cut keys).